Does infrequent ejaculation lead to changes in sperm DNA?
I found a page stating that infrequent ejaculation can lead to changes in
sperm DNA. It also suggests that ejaculating every 2-3 days is beneficial
for maintaining good sperm DNA integrity.
Does infrequent ejaculation lead to changes in sperm DNA?

I didn't look closely, however from a quick look this article contradicts what you found, as it says sperm regenerates so if kept unreleased, it will simply be replaced with fresh semen. Also, as you are challenging a notable claim, this question might better fit Skeptics.SE site. Edit: there's even a related question there.

@ShadowWizard the string "DNA" doesn't seem to appear in the article that you shared.

@user1271772 hence only a comment, if I'd wanted to answer I would look for more sources, but the point was to show that since sperm is replaced if not released, and fresh sperm means fresh DNA, even if it's not written directly. I do agree that specific source isn't enough for answer.
